# Como carregar duas tabelas em um só select (html)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Tenho duas tabelas de clientes, uma que se chama **pessoafisica** e outra que se chama **pessoajuridica** Eu preciso de carregar as duas tabelas dentro de 1(um select) utilizando php e codeigniter 3.6.

Conseguir carregar a tabela de pessoafisica, como segue o código no controller e na view abaixo, lembrando que a tabela Atendimento possui as chaves estrangeiras da tabela pessoafisica (fkcodpf) e da tabela pessoajuridica (fkcodpj):

CONTROLOADOR Atendimento

```
class Atendimento extends CI_Controller {

public function cadastro() {


    $dados['pessoafisica'] = $this->db->get('pessoafisica')->result();        
    $this->load->view('includes/html_header');
    $this->load->view('includes/menu');
    $this->load->view('cadastrar/cad_atendimento', $dados);
}
}
```

VIEW de Cadastro do Atendimento (select)

```
<label>Nome do Cliente</label>
<select id="fkcodpf" name="fkcodpf" class="form-control" >
<option value=""></option>  
<?php foreach ($pessoafisica as $pf) { ?>
<option value="<?= $pf->codpf ?>"> <?= $pf->nomepessoafisica; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Mas como fazer para carregar junto nesse select, a tabela pessoajuridica? Se possível ordenando pelo nomepessoafisica, seguido do nomepessoajuridica?

[image: Este é o select que preciso carregar meus clientes, para efetuar um cadastro de atendimento]

Comment: Será que se voce usar subqueris no SQL poderia resolver o seu problema ?

Comment: No caso teria de usar `$this->db->query("SELECT  ....")`

Comment: teria como me explicar melhor Marcelo? como ficaria essa query no Controller e como eu chamaria ela na View? obrigado.

Comment: Não sei exatamente o que voce quer fazer juntando essas duas tabelas. Voce pode tar dando uma olhada em alguns tutoriais na internet de como fazer subqueries, facil

Comment: Isso esta agarrando meu projeto de escritorio se advocacia pessoal. Preciso de fazer isso pois um atendimento pode ser feito a uma pessoa fisica ou juridica. E como eu fiz uma tabela para cada tipo de pessoa, tenho q sempre manipular duas tabelas.

Comment: penso que subqueries nao resolve o meu problema, pois as tabelas nao tem relacao uma com a outra. Ou nao precisa ter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito, vc quer fazer uma mesclagem dos dados da tabela de pessoas físicas com os dados das tabelas de pessoas jurídicas dentro de um único elemento `select`. Nem vou fazer observações no que se refere à complicação que vc terá pra diferenciar os dados na aplicação (quem é PJ e quem é PF), pois vc já deve ter isso em mente na hora da validação. Na minha opinião vc deveria usar outro elemento e *JavaScript*, mas esse não é o escopo da pergunta.

Mas cabe observar que isso deve ficar pesado pra carregar. Se a máquina do cliente não for lá essas coisas, não vai ficar engraçado de usar. Eu simulei 4290 registros, e não foi muito legal o tempo de resposta.

Dito isso, até onde vi, o `CodeIgniter`não tem, na biblioteca nativa, a possibilidade de executar um `UNION`. Mas tem a possibilidade de executar uma `QUERY` em formato texto ([leia mais aqui](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-basics)).

Sabendo disso, segue o método do *model*:

```
function select_duas_tabelas(){
        $sql = "SELECT cpf as id,nome FROM tb_pessoa_fisica ";
        $sql.= "UNION ALL ";
        $sql.= "SELECT cnpj,nome FROM tb_pessoa_juridica ";
        $sql.= "ORDER BY nome ASC";
        $query = $this->db1->query($sql);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Basicamente, *cpfs* e *cnpjs* vão ser chamados de 'id' nessa consulta, e assumirão o lugar do id no 'fkcodpf' do seu elemento.

Segue o *controller* carregando os dados para a *view*:

```
function select_duas_tabelas(){
    $data['title'] = $this->lang->line('pages_select_duas_tabelas_title');
    $data['dados'] = $this->teste->select_duas_tabelas();
    $this->template->load('template/index', 'pages/select_duas_tabelas', $data);
}
```

Por fim, segue a *view* mostrando o seu elemento *select* com todos os dados de PF e PJ:

```
<label>Nome do Cliente</label>
<select id="fkcodpf" name="fkcodpf" class="form-control" >
    <option value=""></option>  
    <?php
    foreach ($dados as $p) { ?>
        <option value="<?=$p['id']?>"><?=$p['nome'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

É isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado @ShutUpMagda, vou testar aqui, você poderia me dá alguma dica de como fazer isso de forma mais eficiente sem comprometer muito a performance da aplicação? Obrigado.